# What is the name of ducting I am looking for if they even make it?

Tags: ducts, terminology

I am looking for something like [this](http://www.progressive-growth.com/proddetail.php?prod=11058) but with an additional hole.

[image]

Do they make this part, and if so what would it be called?

Comment: Yes, in the HVAC world, they are called "Cross Tee's"

Comment: Nice website, Cheech.

Comment: I would expect the site is selling single wall air duct, but the image is for double wall type B vent pipe. Just sayin'.

Comment: @Dylan Maybe I'm way off-base but your account here is linked to your stackoverflow and several other SE accounts, do you really want to publicize that you're shopping for hydro gardening equipment? People will assume one thing, like dbracey has.

Comment: @Qes, thanks for your concern and your not way off-base. For the record I am cooling a room with a number of computers (20+) and other heat generating electrical equipment inside a small room which needs to be cooled. If I was going to grow marijuana I surely wouldn't ask for advice on an account that has my name, job description, and employer linked to it.

Comment: Nor does interest in hydro gardening mean that.  Other reasons are food snobs growing their own herbs, seed-purity types cultivating food seeds (which you do in controlled space to avoid contamination with hybrid or GMO species), people with chronic illnesses finding relief in traditional Chinese medicine herbs, but disliking the polluted dreck coming from China, etc.  I even know someone who cultivates milkweed to support monarch butterflies.  The is great satisfaction and magic in home cultivation.  Why is this a lost art?

Comment: I don't think you can get a B-vent cross tee, at least I hope not. It'd have to be a dual wye to direct the exhaust gasses.

Answer (score 1):

Don't know about ducts specifically, but that shaped joint is usually called a cross in other problem domains.

http://xmzxl.en.alibaba.com/product/299354123-210434489/Cross_joint.html